# Converting VBA function (Duplicate Extractor) to Google app script

Tags: javascript, vba, google-sheets

I have a VBA function(ExtractDuplicates(stext As String, Separator As String, 
Optional Outputseparator As String = "") As String, When applied extracts the duplicate text from a cell to another cell. For E.g "Maya and Maya went to party" when the function applied it will extract "Maya" and show it to the other cell.
I need the same function for my google sheet. Somehow its not possible for me to manipulate it according to google script.

```
Public Function ExtractDuplicates(stext As String, Separator As String, 
Optional Outputseparator As String = "") As String
Dim arr As Variant
Dim myDic As Object
Dim outDic As Object
Dim L As Long
arr = Split(stext, Separator)
If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
Set myDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set outDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For L = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
If Not myDic.exists(arr(L)) Then
myDic(arr(L)) = 0
Else:
outDic(arr(L)) = 0
End If
Next
ExtractDuplicates = Join(outDic.keys, Outputseparator)
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(SPLIT(A1," "),COUNTIF(SPLIT(A1," "),SPLIT(A1," "))-1)))
```

- SPLIT by " "
- FILTER,if count>1
- return the UNIQUE values in filtered array
- You may add JOIN,if needed.

Comment: This formula works but when there are 2 or more duplicates it shows the result with result separately I need it to show the whole thing with in one cell.

Comment: I tried This      =UNIQUE(CONCATENATE(FILTER(SPLIT(E3," "),COUNTIF(SPLIT(E3," "),SPLIT(E3," "))-1)))        It works fine but there is no spacing left with in the duplicate result

Comment: Trust me, I have tried and I am not able to get the desired result. I am a little naive about all these functions. Please help! :(

Comment: @|'-'| Thanks a tonne for help this has been bothering me since 2 days. Can I ask you one more question why only -1 works in the formula and what is the role of that?